# Use kotlin lib in java call fun

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I use a librery that is writed by kotlin in android studio project

```
    class Builder<S> private constructor(val dateSelector: DateSelector<S>) {
     var calendarConstraints: CalendarConstraints? =null
    /** Sets the first, last, and starting [Month].  */
    fun setCalendarConstraints(bounds: CalendarConstraints?): Builder<S> {
        calendarConstraints = bounds
        return this
    }
    /** Creates a [MaterialDatePicker] with the provided options.  */
     companion object {            
        /**
         * Used to create a Builder that allows for choosing a single date in the `MaterialDatePicker`.
         */
        fun datePicker(): Builder<Long?> {
            return Builder(SingleDateSelector())
        }
    }
}
```

when I want to use setCalendarConstraints in java class activity

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder.Companion.datePicker().setTitleText(R.string.selectdate).setCalendarConstraints(constraints).build();
```

I have this error for when call setCalendarConstraints

Ambiguous method call. Both setCalendarConstraints (CalendarConstraints) in Builder and setCalendarConstraints
(CalendarConstraints) in Builder match

which i can split default setter and fun in java?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the library, I guess only the following alternative options can help, modifying the source code of the library:

1. Make `calendarConstraints` property private.
2. Rename `calendarConstraints` property to something else.
3. Rename `setCalendarConstraints` method to something else.
4. Add some additional parameter to `setCalendarConstraints` method.
5. Add `@JvmField` annotation to `calendarConstraints` property:

   ```
   @JvmField
   var calendarConstraints: CalendarConstraints? = null
   ```

Or you can use **Kotlin** instead of **Java** in the project where you are working with this library.

Comment: I  added librery to the project as a package from GitHub. Also, this problem may be elsewhere. The solution in Java is more important to me.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there is no solution for this case in Java except of what I suggested. Maybe there is a workaround using java reflection, but I'm not sure.